# YuGiOh Card effect

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Raidraptor last strix’s ability states that when use use its effect to special summon an XYZ monster it negates it’s effect and is destroyed in the end phase. but if I was summoning Raidraptor ultimate falcon (who is immune to card effects) which ones effect would negate the other? and would ultimate falcon still be destroyed in the end phase?

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raidraptor last strix's effect would negate that of Ultimate Falcon, because Ultimate Falcon would be brought in using last strix's ability, which means the effext of ultimate falcon would be negated completely. The way to keep ultimate out would be to use last strix to bring out satellite cannon falcon, then double xyz change into ultimate. Satellite cannon would no longer be on the field (xyz material do not count as being on the field), and so the last part of last strix's effect would be unable to destroy it, and Ultimate cannon would be left on the field, with one material.